# Divisiones en Bash con decimales

Tags: bash, division

Estoy tratando de hacer una división en bash con este código:

```
#!/bin/bash

dividendo=10
divisor=3

resultado=$(echo "scale=3; $dividento/$divisor" | bc)

echo "Resultado: $resultado"
```

Sin embargo, me da este error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

¿Por qué? ¿Cómo lo corrijo?

Comment: defines dividen**d**o (con D) pero usas dividen**t**o (con T), ¿es esto así en tu código?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer una división con `bc`, el formato es el que usas:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 10/3" | bc
3.333
$ echo "scale=0; 11/3" | bc
3
$ echo "11/3" | bc
3
$ echo "scale=3; 12/3" | bc
4.000
```

En tu caso estás usando las variables erróneamente.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré como hacerlo:

resultado=`echo "scale=3; $dividendo / $divisor" | bc -l`

Answer (score 0):

Editando en tu código:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dividendo=10
    divisor=3
    
    resultado=$(echo "scale=3; $((dividendo))/$((divisor))" | bc)
    
    echo "Resultado: $resultado"
```

Comment: Donde estaba el error? explicale un poco

Comment: El primer error era que estaba usando 'dividento' en lugar del nombre de su variable 'dividendo'.
Después, para invocar una operación aritmética, con los valores guardados en las variables, debe de hacerlo con el operador apropiado, en este caso (()).

Comment: tenes que editar tu respuesta y no hacer un comentario, porque sino a cualquier lector le sera dificil tener que leer todo para completar tu respuesta.